# Greengrassd service starting issue on Raspberry Pi zero device. it shows “Illegal instruction”?

Tags: pi-zero-w

**AWS greengrass service** configurations problem on Raspberry PI zero. i configured on RPI and when i start the greengrasss service with **"sudo ./greengrassd start"**. It shows error like **"Illegal instruction"**. whats the problem for getting the error

Comment: That error would suggest the software is not compatible with Pi0 / Pi 1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/gg-gs.html#gg-requirements seems to support that. Do you have information that it is compatible with Pi zero?